# Python flask database retrieval

Tags: python, sql, flask

I was creating a login page using flask. Here I am retrieving email and password using sql_alchemy, but it shows error can't concatenate str with int at `if userdetails['Email'] == username and userdetails['Password'] == userpass`.

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if 'user' in session and session['user'] == params['admin_user']:
        return render_template('domain.html')
       if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.form.get('email')
            userpass = request.form.get('password')
            userdetails = User.query.filter_by(Email=username)

            if len(str(userdetails)) > 0:
                if userdetails['Email'] == username and userdetails['Password'] == userpass:
                    session['user'] = username
                    flash('Welcome' + session['Name'] + '! You have been successfully logged in', 'success')
                    return render_template('domain.html')
                else:

                    flash('Password does not match.', 'danger')
                    return render_template('user_login.html')
            else:
                flash('User not found.', 'danger')
                return render_template('user_login.html')
        return render_template('user_login.html')
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, images of code are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The error is telling you that you have tried to use an integer where a string was expected, is your username or password an integer? Could you try converting them to strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to add `.one()` at the end of

`userdetails = User.query.filter_by(Email=username)`

It should look like this: `userdetails = User.query.filter_by(Email=username).one()`

If I am not mistaken, `filter_by` returns a list of the results rather than the result itself.

Edit: I have seen that you also use `userdetails` to check if there is any matches in the query.

Then I would advise you to keep it as is on the query side, and add another variable under the if statement that checks for result match. The final version should be something like this:

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if 'user' in session and session['user'] == params['admin_user']:
        return render_template('domain.html')
       if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.form.get('email')
            userpass = request.form.get('password')
            userdetails = User.query.filter_by(Email=username)

            if userdetails.count() > 0:
                user = userdetails.one()
                if user['Email'] == username and user['Password'] == userpass:
                    session['user'] = username
                    flash('Welcome' + session['Name'] + '! You have been successfully logged in', 'success')
                    return render_template('domain.html')
                else:

                    flash('Password does not match.', 'danger')
                    return render_template('user_login.html')
            else:
                flash('User not found.', 'danger')
                return render_template('user_login.html')
        return render_template('user_login.html')
```